# Restricting access to Google Web Services API for my Android application only

Tags: android, google-places-api

This is a follow-up for [another question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34381323/how-to-parse-address-from-google-places-geodataapi-for-android-address-compone/39181185).

Is there any way to restrict access to Google Web Services API (in my case [Places API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/)) for my Android application only?
I want to get the "address_components" field from [place details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResults) and I cannot use [Android API function](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/GeoDataApi.html#getPlaceById(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String...)) because that field is absent in the [returned object](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place).

I've selected Android app key restriction and entered my app details (package name + SHA-1 certificate fingerprint) in Google Developer Console. I'm receiving "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key ..." error message, that is expected.

I've tried to fill "X-Android-Package" and "X-Android-Cert" headers, but noting changed. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

The Android application restriction only works if you're using the key with the Android API, alas (the docs [could be more clear](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#keysystem) about this).

If you're planning to call the web service from your mobile app, then the preferred approach is to proxy mobile calls through a service so that the API key isn't embedded in the mobile app. There's more on this approach in [this blog post](https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2016/09/making-most-of-google-maps-web-service.html), which links to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QqOYZ5Yu47Y&feature=youtu.be).

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing response from Cloud Support Team for this issue. Hope it works.

To solve this issue, you have two options:

1. Keep using the Nearby Search web service
   Web services are only compatible with API key restricted to IP addresses.

Since you are making requests from a mobile app environment, the IP addresses will be different depending where the user is connected. As a workaround, you can set up a proxy server:
https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices
#mobile-ws-static-web

Once this is done, restrict your API key by the proxy server's IP address(es).

2. Switch your implementation to Places Library's Nearby Search
   In this configuration, requests are made from the client side. Set website restrictions to your API key in this format (where domain.com is your website):
   https:// ___________________.com